# MongooseError: Operation `devices.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to run automation test in node.js but I got the above error.

Its not a connection problem, because a minute before it I tried to create user in mongodb using mongoose and secceed.

Do you have any idea?

My test is:

```js
it('should be error in createing users with the same id', async () => {
    const error = Device.create([{userId:'9573468'}, {userId:'9573468'}])
    return expect(!!error).toBe(true)
})
```

The other fields in user model are not required.

Comment: can you provide some code

Comment: MURHAF AL-MSRI - see my edited question

Comment: if the Device where a mongodb model then you need insertMany to create more than one doc.
what package do you use?